# Delete all files in directory (but not directory) - one liner solution

Tags: java, file-io, apache-commons-io

I want to delete all files inside ABC directory.

When I tried with `FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("C:/test/ABC/"));` it also deletes folder ABC.

Is there a one liner solution where I can delete files inside directory but not directory?

Comment: Thats because .deleteDirectory (even the name implies it) is used for deleting directory's.  It will get the directory it is in if the file isn't a directory.

Comment: Try looking for other functions inside the FileUtils class, that delete files instead of directory's.

Comment: http://www.javacodeexamples.com/java-delete-file-example/

Comment: Why do you specifically need a one-liner? Performance can't be the criteria, because any 3rd party library method, will do that recursively only. So it would give you the same performance?

Comment: One thing you can do is delete the directory and then re-create it. We found that using `rm -rf directory; mkdir directory` was faster than using `FileUtils.cleanDirectory`.

Answer (score 443, accepted):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

FileUtils.cleanDirectory(directory);
```

There is this method available in the same file. This will also recursively deletes all sub-folders and files under them.

Docs: [`org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#cleanDirectory(java.io.File))

Comment: Nice one, also to prevent people from having to look this up; here's the import: import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

Comment: I still do have to look up why the import cannot be found. It's because one must [download it from apache.org](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi).

Comment: pretty solution. Check this lib by gradle: compile "commons-io:commons-io:+"

Comment: [Gradle dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io) - compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'.

Comment: Note, we found calling `rm -rf directory` was much more efficient than using `FileUtils.cleanDirectory`.

Comment: @Jaydev I thought we're supposed to use `implementation` instead of `compile`?

Comment: Don't forget to add in `build.gradle`: `dependencies { implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'}`

Answer (score 310):

Do you mean like?

```
for(File file: dir.listFiles()) 
    if (!file.isDirectory()) 
        file.delete();
```

This will only delete files, not directories.

Comment: This is definitley the better answer, since it does not use an external lib!

Comment: @AlexWien But OP is already using that library. You must have noticed that BTW.

Comment: @amar but even then: when there is a standard method there is absolutley no reason to use an external one which does the same thing. One day he might want to get rid of the lib, or the lib is not supported anymore, or is not allowed to use the lib for license reasons, etc. (This all might not be an issue for this specific lib, but applies to many other ones)

Comment: This will fail to delete everything if you have subdirectories inside the root "dir" directory.

Comment: @TiagoT True, this will not delete sub-directories which are not empty.

Comment: @AlexWien - Not necessarily, as many nontrivial projects will _already_ be directly or indirectly (as a transitive dependency) referencing `commons-io`.  No reason not to use the library if it's already there anyways.  However, certainly a better answer in contexts where `commons-io` is unavailable for whatever reason.  Such as [on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359163/apache-commons-io-on-android).

Comment: `for(File file: dir.listFiles())` is probably meant as.... `for (File file : new java.io.File("C:\\DeleteMeFolder").listFiles())` ...

Comment: @Peter: How can I delete all files till yesterday in a directory (but not directory) - one liner solution?

Comment: @venkat you can delete all files with a modification date of more than 24 hours.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is far more elegant. No external dependency and does exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: This won't work for directories with huge number of files since `listFiles()` fails by memory.

Comment: Since in some cases listFiles() may return null (dir does not exist, for example), it is better to add a check to avoid NPE crashes.

Answer (score 74):

Peter Lawrey's answer is great because it is simple and not depending on anything special, and it's the way you should do it. If you need something that removes subdirectories and their contents as well, use recursion:

```
void purgeDirectory(File dir) {
    for (File file: dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory())
            purgeDirectory(file);
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

To spare subdirectories and their contents (part of your question), modify as follows:

```
void purgeDirectoryButKeepSubDirectories(File dir) {
    for (File file: dir.listFiles()) {
        if (!file.isDirectory())
            file.delete();
    }
}
```

Or, since you wanted a one-line solution:

```
for (File file: dir.listFiles())
    if (!file.isDirectory())
        file.delete();
```

Using an external library for such a trivial task is not a good idea unless you need this library for something else anyway, in which case it is preferrable to use existing code. You appear to be using the Apache library anyway so use its `FileUtils.cleanDirectory()` method.

Comment: On the other hand, if nobody is the first to use the external library, then it's less likely that others will expect to find similar behavior in that external library, and less likely that they will look there... don't we have enough Not Invented Here out there? If the library is cohesive and easy to add to my project, then I almost always prefer to add the library.

Answer (score 50):

## Java 8 Stream

This deletes only files from **ABC** (sub-directories are untouched):

```
Arrays.stream(new File("C:/test/ABC/").listFiles()).forEach(File::delete);
```

---

This deletes only files from **ABC** (and sub-directories):

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/test/ABC/"))
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .map(Path::toFile)
                .forEach(File::delete);
```

^ This version requires handling the IOException

Comment: The second one doesn't delete the sub-directories (tested)

Comment: @edwise Yes, it deletes all files from ABC and all files from the sub-directories. The English is a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 14):

Or to use this in Java 8:

```
try {
  Files.newDirectoryStream( directory ).forEach( file -> {
    try { Files.delete( file ); }
    catch ( IOException e ) { throw new UncheckedIOException(e); }
  } );
}
catch ( IOException e ) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It's a pity the exception handling is so bulky, otherwise it would be a one-liner ...

Comment: How do you know that file *IS* a file actually and not a directory?

Comment: It also delete directory, so it's not a solution to the problem from the topic

Answer (score 7):

#### `rm -rf` was *much* more performant than `FileUtils.cleanDirectory`.

Not a one-liner solution but after extensive benchmarking, we found that using `rm -rf` was multiple times faster than using `FileUtils.cleanDirectory`.

Of course, if you have a small or simple directory, it won't matter but in our case we had multiple gigabytes and deeply nested sub directories where it would take over 10 minutes with `FileUtils.cleanDirectory` and only 1 minute with `rm -rf`.

Here's our rough Java implementation to do that:

```
// Delete directory given and all subdirectories and files (i.e. recursively).
//
static public boolean clearDirectory( File file ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    if ( file.exists() ) {

        String deleteCommand = "rm -rf " + file.getAbsolutePath();
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        Process process = runtime.exec( deleteCommand );
        process.waitFor();

        file.mkdirs(); // Since we only want to clear the directory and not delete it, we need to re-create the directory.

        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Worth trying if you're dealing with large or complex directories.

Answer (score 6):

```
public class DeleteFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path="D:\test"; 
        File file = new File(path);
        File[] files = file.listFiles(); 
        for (File f:files) 
        {if (f.isFile() && f.exists) 
            { f.delete();
system.out.println("successfully deleted");
            }else{
system.out.println("cant delete a file due to open or error");
} }  }}
```

Comment: Great... This is the code sample that i was looking for despite minor syntax errors.  Just needed to replace .exists with .exists() and replace system.out with System. out.

Answer (score 3):

For deleting all files from directory say "C:\Example"

```
File file = new File("C:\\Example");      
String[] myFiles;    
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    myFiles = file.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {
        File myFile = new File(file, myFiles[i]); 
        myFile.delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work (based on NonlinearFruit previous answer):

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/test/ABC/"))
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .map(Path::toFile)
                .filter(item -> !item.getPath().equals("C:/test/ABC/"))
                .forEach(File::delete);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Another Java 8 Stream solution to delete all the content of a folder, sub directories included, but not the folder itself.

Usage:

```
Path folder = Paths.get("/tmp/folder");
CleanFolder.clean(folder);
```

and the code:

```
public interface CleanFolder {
    static void clean(Path folder) throws IOException {

        Function<Path, Stream<Path>> walk = p -> {
            try { return Files.walk(p);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return Stream.empty();
        }};

        Consumer<Path> delete = p -> {
            try {
                Files.delete(p);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        };

        Files.list(folder)
            .flatMap(walk)
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .forEach(delete);
    }
}
```

The problem with every stream solution involving Files.walk or Files.delete is that these methods throws IOException which are a pain to handle in streams.

I tried to create a solution which is more concise as possible.

Comment: Rather then returning a null in the walk Function it would be better to return an empty stream (Stream.empty()). It's cleaner and the function always returns a stream. Null should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Thanks, I improved the answer with your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

```
package com;
import java.io.File;
public class Delete {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String files; 
        File file = new File("D:\\del\\yc\\gh");
        File[] listOfFiles = file.listFiles(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
        {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
            {
                files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                System.out.println(files);
                if(!files.equalsIgnoreCase("Scan.pdf"))
                {
                    boolean issuccess=new File(listOfFiles[i].toString()).delete();
                    System.err.println("Deletion Success "+issuccess);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to delete all files remove

```
if(!files.equalsIgnoreCase("Scan.pdf"))
```

statement it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can make it as:

```
fun File.deleteDirContent(){
   this.walkBottomUp()
       .filter { it != this }
       .forEach { it.deleteRecursively() }
}
```

and use this function as:

```
dir.deleteDirContent()
```

Answer (score 0):

In java 8, simply use:

```
public void clearDirectory(Path directory){
    if (Files.exists(directory)) {
            Files.list(directory)
                 .forEach(
                         path -> {
                             try {
                                 if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
                                     clearDirectory(path);
                                 }
                                 Files.delete(path);
                             } catch (IOException e) {
                                 // todo handle exception
                             }
                         }
                 );
        }
}
```