# Apache Commons IO on Android

Tags: java, android, apache-commons

I'm developing an Android application that uses [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi), **commons-io-2.4-bin.tar.gz**.

And I get some errors, one of them:

```
Could not find method java.lang.String.getBytes, referenced from method org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toInputStream
```

I think I don't have to worry about it, isn't it?

**Is there another specific Android library that I can use instead of Apache Commons IO?**

I'm using it here:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler;

import android.util.Log;

public class CustomResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler
{

    private ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler = new DefaultResponseErrorHandler();

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        String theString = IOUtils.toString(response.getBody());
        Log.v("Error Handler", theString);
        CustomException exception = new CustomException();
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("code", response.getStatusCode().toString());
        properties.put("body", theString);
        properties.put("header", response.getHeaders());
        exception.setProperties(properties);

        throw exception;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        return errorHandler.hasError(response);
    }

}
```

On this line:

```
String theString = IOUtils.toString(response.getBody());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) might be a good replacement for you. [Their wiki](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Compatibility) claims they're fully compatible with Android:

> Guava 11.0.2 and earlier are fully compatible with Android, but more recent Android versions may be required for the latest Guava releases. In particular, NavigableSet and other extensions added in Java 6 (used by Guava 12 and above) were added in Android API version 9, corresponding with Gingerbread.
>
> (Android programmers concerned with Guava's large JAR size are advised to use ProGuard to get only the parts of Guava they need. Guava is one of the most common dependencies for Android applications.)

For the Guava equivalent of `IOUtils.toString()` check the following question: [Guava equivalent for IOUtils.toString(InputStream)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4185665/321366)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I use ProGuard to get only the parts of Guava I need?

Comment: @VansFannel: It's documented on the wiki page: [UsingProGuardWithGuava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava), if you want more information I think it's best to open a new question.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the Apache Commons IO library source, and then packaging it to Android :) I have packaged it in a repo [here](https://github.com/smannlymann/ApacheCommonsIO-for-Android). Just import it into your IDE of choice!